# How can I object-browse dependencies similar to how I used to be able to browse references in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to learn .Net Core, moving there from the .Net Framework.

.Net Framework projects had references. .Net Core has dependencies. Conceptually and functionally identical, but still different in execution in one specific way.

When working with a .Net Framework project, from the solution explorer, I can expand the project references, right-click, and the context menu has an option to browse the contents of the reference. Look at methods, classes, structs, etc.

I'm not finding anything like that with .Net Core.

The only dependency I have right now is the Microsoft.NETCore.App, and when I expand it in the solution explorer, I see a lot. But I can't browse any of them, like I can references.

What am I missing so that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On solution explorer change tab to Class View, then search any dependency on the search box, right click over a result and select on the context menu Browse Definition and you will be able to see classes, methods and related objects in the window Object Browser.

[image]